# Inverse Laplace Transform by Complex Inversion Theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

The questions asks to find $F(t) = L^{-1}\{s^{-1/2}e^{-1/s}\}$

I've made a branch cut along the negative real axis and produced a contour similar to this:
[image]

Integration along segments BE, LA go to 0 and since $f(s)$ has no singularities within the contour, the entire integration around it is 0 and we can find $F(t)$ as the integration along AB. So I have:

F(t) = $\int_{AB}$ = - ($\int_{EH}$ + $\int_{HJK}$ + $\int_{KL}$)

EH: Take $s=xe^{i\pi}$

Then $$\int_{EH}  =\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} \frac{e^{st-1/s}}{\sqrt s} ds =\int_{R}^{\epsilon} \frac{ie^{1/x-xt}}{\sqrt x} dx$$

Similarly for KL: Take $s=xe^{-i\pi}$

Then $$\int_{KL} =\int_{-\epsilon}^{-R} \frac{e^{st-1/s}}{\sqrt s} ds =\int_{\epsilon}^{R} \frac{ie^{1/x-xt}}{\sqrt x} dx$$

HJK: Take $s=\epsilon e^{i\theta}$

Then $$\int_{HJK} =\int_{\pi}^{-\pi} \frac{e^{st-1/s}}{\sqrt s} ds =\int_{\pi}^{-\pi} \frac{e^{\epsilon t e^{i\theta}-1/\epsilon e^{i\theta}}}{\sqrt \epsilon e^{i\theta /2}} i\sqrt \epsilon e^{i\theta /2} ds =\int_{\pi}^{-\pi} \sqrt{\epsilon} ie^{\epsilon t e^{i\theta} - (\epsilon te^{i\theta})^{-1}+ i\theta/2} dx$$

Now, assuming these are correct (which might not be wise):

$$F(t) = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{R\to \infty, \epsilon \to 0} \int_{R}^{\epsilon} \frac{ie^{1/x-xt}}{\sqrt x} dx + \int_{\epsilon}^{R} \frac{ie^{1/x-xt}}{\sqrt x} dx + \int_{\pi}^{-\pi} \sqrt{\epsilon} ie^{\epsilon t e^{i\theta} - (\epsilon te^{i\theta})^{-1}+ i\theta/2} dx$$

$$\therefore F(t) = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{R\to \infty, \epsilon \to 0} \int_{\pi}^{-\pi} \sqrt{\epsilon} e^{\epsilon t e^{i\theta} - (\epsilon te^{i\theta})^{-1}+ i\theta/2} dx$$

I'm stuck here. Instructions were to let $\epsilon \to t^{-1/2}$ rather than 0 but I don't understand why and I can't evaluate this integral. I know the answer is $\frac{\cos(2\sqrt t)}{\sqrt{\pi t}}$ from using a different method. Also how should I show the branch points analytically?

Comment: The Maple code $$ with(inttrans):
invlaplace(exp(-1/s)/s, s, t); $$ outputs $${{\rm J}\left(0,\,2\,\sqrt {t}\right)} .$$